# Collision between Box Collider 2D and Polygon Collider 2D not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, rigid-bodies

Currently I am working on a networked 2d platform game.

My player is an empty object which serves as a parent to my actual graphics etc. The empty object has a `rigidbody (3d)` attached to it as it needs to have one in order to use the `configurable joint` component ( note: I move my player around using this 3d rigid body).The player body however, a child to the graphics, has a `box collider 2d` attached to it as it after all it is a 2d game and has to collide with other 2d objects.

My platforms have `polygon collider 2d`s attached to them (which is connected to a platform effector if that is worth mentioning).

Now, even though both my player body (which is a child to graphics which is a child to my player object) and my platforms have `2d colliders` on them they do not collide and can simply go inside each other (neither of them is marked as `isTrigger`).

In order to solve this I thought I would add a  `rigidbody 2D` to the player body and see if that would do anything. Now upon adding the `rigidbody 2D` collisions did work but as soon as I made the `rigidbody 2D` have all position and rotation constraints ticked or as soon as I made it `kinematic` or `static` it would cease to collide with my platforms. The problem is I need to have the `rigidbody 2D` be `static` or not be able to move as I am currently moving my player object using the `rigidbody (3d)` attached to it and do not want any additional movement of the player body upon colliding with objects.

I know this is quite a lot of information, so if you have any questions or would like further information just comment and I will be quick to respond. Thank you :-)!

Edit:
2d ray casts are also unable to hit the player body `box collider 2D`

Edit 2:
So to recap:

If either the player body or the platform has a `rigidbody 2d` that is not static (dynamic) and can move collisions work. However currently I only have a `rigidbody 2D` on my player body which has to be static though (as explained earlier) as well as a `box collider 2d`. My platform(s) on the other hand currently only has a `polygon collider 2d` as I do not see why it would need a `rigidbody 2D`.

Comment: Since this question is not so much about C# as it is about Unity, you might want to try over on https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/

Comment: yeah I will try... though as this problem is pretty unique to coders I think it is also an appropriate question for Stack Overflow. @TimothyGroote

Comment: Just to be sure, can you sum up for each one of your two objects (platform and player body) if they have a rigidbody / are static / are kinematic when they don't collide?

Comment: Yes will do @Isuka

Comment: There you go @Isuka

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A static collider won't detect the collision with another collider if it doesn't have a rigidbody, if it is static or if it has a kinematic rigidbody. At least one of your two objects needs to not be static and to have a rigidbody which is not kinematic to be correctly detected. So you do need to add a Rigidbody2D to your platform.

When you have a doubt about why a collider wouldn't collide with another one, always refer to [this page](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html) of Unity's documentation which sums up which kind of collider will collide with another one.

Comment: but as I can't make my player body's rigidbody non-static how should I go about not making my platforms move upon collision while having a non static rigid body? (thanks a lot for your answer)

Comment: Don't get me wrong: your player body's collider can be static. But you just have to add a Rigidbody2D to your platform object without making it static or kinematic. It should work this way.

Comment: thank you a lot I will try to do so... (and then accept your answer)

Comment: yeah, so like mentioned, I now have the problem that my platforms move when I land on them as they have a rigid body that is dynamic...(please just help me with this one last thing and I will accept your answer)

Comment: @RaZ I think like it's a different question though. This answer was mainly to answer your base question: why your collider wouldn't detect the other one. You should maybe open a different thread to ask how to move your character on platforms without making any of them move.

Comment: Yes, even though I your answer did not really help me I guess it did answer the question... thanks for your help anyways

Answer (score 0):

Rigidbody2D can't collide with Rigidbody3D, here's a workaround though

http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/580769/can-rigidbody-2d-collide-with-3d-colliders.html

Comment: why would any Rigidbody2D have to collide with Rigidbody3D?

Comment: Your platform has polygon collider which is 2D and your player has rigidbody3D and 2D colliders - which means they won't work together as far as I know.

Comment: oh, ok this is starting to make more sense... do they still not work together even though they are not on the same object, as one is on the parent and the other is on a child

Comment: One of your objects has to have rigidbody in order to collide, 3D rigidbody only collides with 3D colliders, if you have your collider on a different game object than your rigidbody is - it won't trigger any collisions. They have to be on the same game object and of the same type (2D/3D).
So you need to have 2D rigidbody with 2D collider on your parent game object in order for it to collide with 2D polygon collider platform

Comment: Ok I will try this solution, and if it works for me I will accept you answer

Comment: Sad to hear that